# Split-apply-combine in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Is there an SQLite equivalent of `by` or the split-apply-combine strategy?

Specifically, I have a table with columns `firm,flag`. `firm` is an integer that takes on a few hundred values (a firm id), `flag` is an integer taking on the values {0,1}.  There are hundreds of entries per firm.  I would like to compute the mean of flag for each firm, then store that in the same table (not efficient, I know, as each value will be repeated multiple times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a subquery:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET FlagAverage = (SELECT AVG(flag)
                   FROM MyTable AS T2
                   WHERE T2.firm = MyTable.firm)
```